# Как пропускать ненужные индексы?

Tags: javascript

```
var a  = 0; 
label = a++;
```

Он добавляет индекс от нуля и  попорядку 1,2,3 и тд.тп а если мне надо пропустить индексы 3 5 ,10, 34 ну или ещё какието ...Как такое сделать ?писать по одному это  неправильно как то

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let i = 0;

if(![3 5 ,10, 34].includes(i + 1))
  i++;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Для примера, можно определить массив индексов, которые Вы хотите пропустить, затем уже, будь то цикл или рекурсивная функция - делаете, что Вам нужно, пример:

```js
var arr = [1, 5, 7]; // массив индексов
    
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (arr.indexOf(i) >= 0) {  // проверяем, есть элемент в нашем массиве индексов?
        alert(i + ' - Элемент содержится');
        continue; // прекратить текущую итерацию и начать новую
    }
    alert(i + ' - Элемент отсутствует');
}
```

Для проверки, содержится ли элемент в массиве можно использовать как `indexOf`, так и `includes`. Можно и `findValue`, но это менее удобно, пример как идея, способов много.
Запись `arr.indexOf(i) >= 0` эквивалентна записи `arr.includes(i)`.

Comment: ваш метод обрабатывается не корректо

Comment: @elik, Вы не могли бы уточнить, что именно не корректно? )

Comment: все  элементы отсутсвуют

Comment: или я чтото не так понел ))))

Comment: @elik, а Вы нажмите кнопку **Выполнить код**, прежде чем дать ответ, я проверил. Для элементов из массива индексов пишет *Элемент содержится*, для остальных *Элемент отсутствует*)

Comment: прошу прощения ,я нажал )просто не заметил как алерт изменился:)<jkmijt Cgfcb,j!